# Insert PHP do_shortcode using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, shortcode

Okay what I am trying to do

```
var $name = phpInfo.contact_form_name;
var $shortcode ="<div><?php echo do_shortcode(" + $name + ");?></div>";
$('#sliding_contact_form_wrapper_box').append("<span class='shortcode_content'>" + $shortcode + "</span>");
```

Results in

```
<div>
<!--?php echo do_shortcode([contact-form-7 id="140" title="Contact form 1_copy"]);?-->
</div>
```

I've tried to use in functions.php as a work around

```
  remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop',99 );

remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop',99 );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'shortcode_unautop',100 );
```

And now I am stumped and not sure what I am missing

Help please!

Comment: you can't execute php with javascript lol, use ajax

Comment: chance of an example ?

Comment: the good old friend google: wordress ajax exemple

Comment: I think that I see what you are trying to do. Try placing this code in a page template (in your theme) and within an inline `<script></script>` rather than in your content editor or within a .js file.

Comment: Take the shortcode out of the javascript and drop it directly into that div where you want it loaded.  Then add a class to the div to "hide" it with css.  You could jquery to toggleClass to make show/hide the form.  Is that what you are trying to do?